# Помощь в выборе инструментария для резервной копии

Tags: python, bat

Поставили задачу: имеется некое древо каталогов с файлами. Необходимо сделать копию этого древа с файлами, а так же переименовать их (каждый файл и каталог имеет приставку в названии 01_*, а следует ее изменить на 02_**). Файлы являются excel таблицами. И каждая excel таблица может содержать ссылку на другую excel таблицу. Т.е. в чем суть, нужно сделать так, чтобы ссылки между файлами сохранились. Проблема в ограничении инструментария. Хотел сделать на python, но стороннего софта не разрешается устанавливать. Есть ли смысл .bat файлами это грохать? Или может что предложите поэффективнее? А может есть возможность без установки питона запустить его на ПК.

Comment: Интересно, как вы сохраните ссылки, если переименуете файлы и каталоги...

Comment: *Файлы являются excel таблицами. И каждая excel таблица может содержать ссылку на другую excel таблицу.* Дохлый номер - ссылки в Excel абсолютные.

Comment: @Akina т.е. их изменение ссылок в excel таблицах возможно только вручную?

Comment: Ну почему... можно попробовать открыть все файлы одновременно (ссылка на открытый файл по идее не должна содержать пути к файлу), потом сохранить в новое местоположение, и затем закрыть с сохранением.

Comment: Можно пробовать  через библиотеки питона для работы с excel, но python нельзя. Чистыми bat сделать замену ссылок врятли прокатит. Имхо задача из разряда вот тебе зубочистка и иди копай...

Comment: @Kers а может в powershell можно сделать, как думаешь стоит на это время тратить?

Comment: `rdiff-backup` не требует установки. А обязательно переименовывать? Какой в этом смысл?

Comment: Если сторонний софт - нельзя, возьмите встроенный.VBS во всех версиях Windows имеется. Хорошо взаимодействует с MS Office.

Comment: @don-rumata сложная и тупая задача на производстве, где раньше ее решали руками, каждый месяц структура каталога копируется, а названия и ссылки вручную менялись. Решил исправить как-то эту ситуацию

Comment: да нашел решение уже с помощью powershell

Comment: Руками я это я понял. Я не понял почему надо менять ссылки в бэкапах и почему нельзя ставить сторонний софт?

Comment: @donRumata сторонний софт никто не будет ставить, так как это единичная задача. А ссылки менять нужно потому что каталог с excel файлами копируется в другое место и ссылки получаются будут указывать на старый каталог, что не нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Решение задачи по копированию и переименованию файлов в .bat файле.

```
@echo off
rem Откуда копируем (файл содержит путь)
set /p whereFile=< where.txt

rem Куда копируем (файл содержит путь)
set /p fromFile=< from.txt

rem Процесс копирования
xcopy %fromFile% %whereFile% /s /e

rem Изменяем приставку файлов на 02*
for /r %whereFile% %%i in (*) do ren %%i 02* 

rem Изменяем приставку папок на 02*
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
for /r "%whereFile%" /d %%a  in (*) do (
  set sValue=%%~nxa
  set newVal=02!sValue:~2!
  rename %%a !newVal!
)
pause
```